# How to map through a stream of Java pairs to consolidate into a single pair after some processing?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Stream of pairs that I wish to map through and return them as a pair of strings, but not before doing something with them, first (I learned that teeing is a possible solution):

```java
Stream<Pair<String, CustomObject>> stream = Stream.of(
  Pair.of("fruits",     Map.of("red","apple",   "yellow", "banana")),
  Pair.of("vegetables", Map.of("red","tomatoe", "yellow", "corn")),
  Pair.of("red meat",   Map.of("cow","beef",    "sheep", "mutton"))
  Pair.of("white meat", Map.of("fish","tuna",   "poultry", "chicken"))
);
Pair<String, String> result = stream.collect(Collectors.teeing(
  Collectors.?(this::parseFirstPair),
  Collectors.?(this::parseSecondPair),
  Pair::of
));
/*
result will be:
Pair<
  "(fruits, vegetables, red meat, white meat)",
  "Red apples, yellow bananas, red tomatoes, yellow corns, cow beef, sheep mutton, fish tuna, poultry chickens are all very nutritious for the human body!"
>
*/
```

I don't wish to group them, I don't wish to use a predicate.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected output? It's not clear at the moment what exactly you're doing.

Comment: @Unmitigated added sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this can indeed be done with `teeing`. The downstreams are just rather complicated compositions of other collectors.

```
Pair<String, String> result = stream.collect(Collectors.teeing(
    Collectors.mapping(Pair::getFirst, Collectors.joining(", ", "(", ")")),
    Collectors.flatMapping(pair -> pair.getSecond().entrySet().stream(),
        Collectors.mapping(entry -> entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue(),
            Collectors.joining(", ", "", " are all very nutritious for the human body!"))),
    Pair::of
));
```

`result.getFirst()` is:

```
(fruits, vegetables, red meat, white meat)
```

This is achieved by a `mapping` collector getting the first of each pair in the stream, and then using `joining` to make the result string, with `", "` as the separator, `"("` as the prefix, and `")"` as the suffix.

`result.getSecond()` is:

```
red apple, yellow banana, red tomatoe, yellow corn, sheep mutton, cow beef, poultry chicken, fish tunaare all very nutritious for the human body!
```

Since the second part of the pairs in the original stream is a map, and you want to process each entry, a `flatMapping` collector had to be used to map to the map entries. Then the entries are mapped to strings, and joined together like in the first downstream.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reduction. Personally i find a combination of [Stream.map()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and [Stream.reduce()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) much easier to read, create and maintain.

```
BinaryOperator<String> stringMerger = (first, second) -> first + ", " + second;
Pair<String, String> result = stream
        .map(p -> Pair.of(p.left(), p.right().entrySet().stream().map(entry -> entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue()).toList()))
        .map(p -> Pair.of(p.left(), String.join(", ", p.right()))) //you can also directly join the stream elements in the previous map() if you want
        .reduce((p1, p2) -> p1.merge(p2, stringMerger, stringMerger))
        .map(pair -> Pair.of(String.format("(%s)", pair.left()), pair.right() + " add some desired text"))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Should not have happened"));
System.out.println(result.left());
System.out.println(result.right());
```

Prints:

```
(fruits, vegetables, red meat, white meat)
yellow banana, red apple, yellow corn, red tomatoe, sheep mutton, cow beef, fish tuna, poultry chicken add some desired text
```

Pair is custom class for this example, since i don't know what the class you use looks like.

```
public record Pair<L, R>(L left, R right) {

  public static <L, R> Pair<L, R> of(L left, R right) {
    return new Pair<>(left, right);
  }

  public Pair<L, R> merge(Pair<L, R> other, BinaryOperator<L> leftMerger, BinaryOperator<R> rightMerger) {
    return of(leftMerger.apply(this.left, other.left), rightMerger.apply(this.right, other.right));
  }
}
```